# RAID card monitoring from Debian OS

Tags: debian, raid, monitoring

We have a custom built Debain OS server with [this raid card](http://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/HDD-Controllers/SATA-Cards/4-Port-PCI-Express-SATA-6Gbps-RAID-Controller-Card~PEXSAT34RH).

Is there anything we can do from the OS side to monitor the raid virtual disks?
A few weeks ago we had a raid degrade and did not know about it until a reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consumer oriented adapter card, and should not be used in professional systems.

I doubt there is any monitoring solution available for this.

I recommend that you get a proper server RAID adapter, or use Linux software RAID instead.

Answer (score 0):

That card has a Marvell 88SE9230 chipset.

I don't know which driver gets loaded in your kernel but you may be lucky and have compatibility with the Marvell support in `smartctl`.  Then you can script something based around `smartctl -a -d marvell /dev/sda` to monitor drive status in your array.